# W7 - Can't install Android SDK due to a blank Java page

Tags: java, android, sdk, installation

I have trouble installing my Android SDK on WIndows 7 64bit. I already installed the latest JDK, but for some reason, when the Android SDK installer checks for Java, I get a blank page

[image: issue]

I can see that the installer tried something, because another window opened in the taskbar, but it disappeared a second later and I'm left with the above, blank page. All the buttons do not work, so I can't perform the trick I've read in a different topic about press back and next again.

I've got no idea whats going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had JDK x32 installed. But I needed x64, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install the JDK manually? [JAVA JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

What happens if you type in your Windows7 cmd "Java"? Do you get Content?

You could try installing the x32 JDK, maybe it will work!

Comment: Actually I did use x32 JDK. Now I tried x64 and it works. I used x32 in the beginning because I also use the x32 SDK, because x64 only works with x64 browsers.